# Convert Series object into meaningful dict - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Lately I got stuck trying to find an elegant solution to the following problem:

I have a Series object (pandas.core.series.Series) with the following values (e.g.) -

```
{1,43234,2,653543,3,436546}
```

I have another datasource on which I want to iterate, and for that I would like to create a dictionary out of the series, with the following format -

```
{1:43234,2:653543,3:436546}
```

Using the function .to_dict is not suitable as it auto-generates the keys.

Can anyone offer an idea?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: `{k:v for k, v in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])}` ...?

Comment: so you want odd indexes to be your keys and even indexes to be your values?

Answer (score 2):

For any indexable iterable – I'm pretty sure `pd.Series` applies – you can convert a `[key, value, key, value, key, value]` sort of thing to a dict by zipping slices with a stride:

```
>>> a = [1,43234,2,653543,3,436546]
>>> dict(zip(a[::2], a[1::2]))
{1: 43234, 2: 653543, 3: 436546}
```